# Parse wikipedia tables

Tags: objective-c, ios, wikipedia

I have a desire for a functionality in my app that lists plug sizes for different countries, and I found a nice wikipedia page that has this data:

[Mains electricity by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country)

If you scroll down you can see that the data is presented into a table. Since there is no Wikipedia API, I have to insert the data into a PLIST right? Is there another way to do this? How can I parse these tables into a dictionary or an array?

Comment: “Since there is no Wikipedia API” What? How did you figure that out? [There most certainly is an API.](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a Wikipedia API Wrapper for Objective-C there you can get the html source of this wikipedia entry. With a DOM Parser you can find the table and loop over the entries and write it into a dictionary.

Unfortunately the table you need doesn't have an id. But you could search for one of the header words in the table step out one element and get the table.

https://github.com/prine/WikiApiObjectiveC

I just checked. These are the only four lines you need to fetch the html source of your desired article.

```
WikipediaHelper *wikiHelper = [[WikipediaHelper alloc] init];
wikiHelper.apiUrl = @"http://en.wikipedia.org";

NSString *searchWord = @"Mains_electricity_by_country";

NSString *htmlSource = [wikiHelper getWikipediaHTMLPage:searchWord];
```

Comment: OK, so this gives me the full source code of the page, but how can I parse out the tables, I was hoping not to get the whole source code of the page but rather find the table part and store it into an nsdictionary. I have done HTML parsing before with a nice API I have, but this source code looks pretty confusing to me...

Comment: Ah I found it, seems to be nested under </td></tr>

Comment: Im not really sure. Somehow this the wikipedia api isn't responding very fast. Check it out, when you call directly the wikipedia api it also takes a while :/ http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Mains_electricity_by_country&rvprop=content&rvparse&format=json&redirects If you find anything which speeds it up, feel free to commit it into the git project ;).

Comment: that doesn't take too long to load

Comment: Would it be better to use that page and get this website text into a string

Comment: Yeah, then you only need a json parser to get it out of there. But this is actually what im doing in my library. Not really sure what makes it slow :/

Comment: Oh yeah, I would have to use a json parser, ill just use yours!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is copying the data and pasting it into your editor of choice.

Then use a combination of column editing, searching and replacing. I tend to use TextWrangler for that, which supports regex search and replace.

It's a one time job, and the number of lines is limited, so the solution probably doesn't need to be perfect - just good and convenient enough.